# Studio One: Trying to use music as background without crossfading multiple events

Tags: daw, audio-editing

I'm not sure if I'm in exactly the right place for this question, so please pardon me if I'm not.  I'm a bit of a novice to Studio One (although I've worked a bit with other DAWs before), so this question is for all the Studio One buffs out there.

I do voiceovers for a show, so I'm trying to find a way to use a piece of music as the "bed" (background) for my voiceover, with the volume lowered 50% or so, and then raise the song's volume after I'm finished speaking for the duration of the music.  I'd LIKE to do it with just one "instance" of the song in Studio One's main editing window, but I haven't found a way to do so:  right now I have to create a duplicate copy of the segment I want with lowered volume, which overlaps slightly with the piece I want at normal volume...then I have to do a crossfade at the overlap section to effect the increase/decrease in volume.  This is time consuming and annoying, and I just KNOW there has to be an easier way to do this:  I just don't know it and can't find it (I tried doing a search in the manual, although I may be using the wrong terms)!  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may get closed as [off-topic](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) since it has nothing to do with music practice, performance, composition, theory, history, etc. Someone around here may be able to answer, but you might have better luck at [SE Sound Design Beta](https://sound.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, David...I thought I saw a couple of questions around here dealing with issues like this (I even saw "Studio One"), but I wasn't sure.  I'll post over there...if it gets closed off, I'll understand.

Comment: @DavidBowling The "What to Ask" section clearly includes "**usage of specific music software or hardware**". Definitely on-topic.

Comment: @Ian -- thanks for the tip, but I've read the help pages many times. This question is about sound production (for a podcast or something), not music. Note that I did not vote to close myself, only tried to point out another possible avenue of inquiry for OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use volume automation to fade or quick cut the volume of the song so it sinks under your dialog.  Right click on your track header and choose Show/Hide Automation from the context menu.
Click the resulting dropdown and choose Volume.  You will see a colored line thru the track.  If you click the line, it creates a small dot.  You can drag that dot up and down to change volume.  If you click again, you create another dot.  You can use this set of dots to create automated fades up or down as you need within the one track.

Comment: Be careful though.  Depending on volume. the music will obscure the voice either a lot or a little.  Why obscure it at all?